# can't open Hyperlink in a div with onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, size

I have two boxes, which can be increased and decreased in size by onclick. But now my Hyperlinks don't work.

CODE:

```js
function changeSize(id, weight, height){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if(elem.getAttribute('style')){
        elem.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
        elem.style.width = weight + 'px';
        elem.style.height = height + 'px';
        elem.style.fontSize = '30px';
    }
}

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kaesten');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = function(){
        changeSize(this.id, 600, 600);
    }
}
```

```css
.kaesten{
 width:240px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:darkgrey;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
 border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('standort', 600, 600); return false;">
  <a href="www.google.de"> text </a>
</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('standort', 600, 600); return false;">
  <a href="www.focus.de"> text </a>
</div>
```

Question: I linked some intranet sites and office documents without the onclick function they open!  How can I make the links work and keep the function?

Comment: I'm confused, they _work_ for me?

Comment: yes it is working. https://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/nhhxkxz3/

Comment: can it be a IE11 problem?

Comment: I linked some intranet sites and office documents without the onclick function they open!

Answer (score 0):

Add `//` at the start of url in hyperlink `href="//www.focus.de"`

```js
function changeSize(id, weight, height){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if(elem.getAttribute('style')){
        elem.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
        elem.style.width = weight + 'px';
        elem.style.height = height + 'px';
        elem.style.fontSize = '30px';
    }
}

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kaesten');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = function(){
        changeSize(this.id, 600, 600);
    }
}
```

```css
.kaesten{
 width:240px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:darkgrey;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
 border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('standort', 600, 600); return false;">
  <a href="//www.google.de"> text </a>
</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('standort', 600, 600); return false;">
  <a href="//www.focus.de"> text </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I linked some intranet sites and office documents without the onclick function they open!

Answer (score 0):

I linked some intranet sites and office documents in my homepage and had the problem that only without the onclick function they open!

Now I deleted the return false; in my HTML :
wrong Code:

```
<div id="box1" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('standort', 600, 600); return false;">   <a href="//www.google.de"> text </a> </div>
```

Right Code:

```
 <div id="box1" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('standort', 600, 600);">   <a href="//www.google.de"> text </a> </div>
```

Now I can open all Links!